# Knowing when a jquery queue is finished

Tags: jquery, queue

I'm using two jQuery queues and i want one of them to dequeue after another is finished. How can I know if the first one is finished? Should I use a third queue??!

Here is what I have:

```
var $q = $({});    
$q.queue('firstQ', function (next) {
    // blah blah
    next();
});

$q.queue('secondQ', function (next) {
    // blah blah
    next();
});

$q.dequeue("firstQ");
$q.dequeue("secondQ");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
.queue().length
```

to detect `.queue()` length and if queue end then it'll return `0`;

Comment: So I should set an interval to check it?

Comment: I need something like "then()"!

Comment: @XIII yup, you can use interval or then